# Compiling ALP Using NASM On Mac

Tags: macos, nasm

Hey guys i am trying to compile ALP in mac os using nasm. i have earlier compiled my programs on ubuntu using nasm and it worked perfectly. but now i have switched to mac. i have updated my nasm to version - 2.11 which is the latest. now when i m trying to compile my program its giving me errors.
i m using these commands to compile

nams -f elf/macho filename.asm

ld -o filename filename.o

after that its giving me this error -

seemajains-MacBook-Air:MIL seemajain$ nasm -f macho32 assign1.asm
seemajains-MacBook-Air:MIL seemajain$ ld -o assign1 assign1.o
ld: warning: -macosx_version_min not specified, assuming 10.8

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"start", referenced from:

```
 implicit entry/start for main executable
 (maybe you meant: _start)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found for inferred architecture i386

can any one pls help me?

Comment: What's "ALP"? Anyway, according to `ld` you haven't put an entry point label in your code. Either add one with the name `ld` suggested (and make it global), or use the `-e` option when linking if you want to use an entry point with a different name.